# How can I assign different range of contacts to different logged in users in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a simple CRM in php and mysql. But stuck at a portion.
I have a table of users which can log-in at same time and access the **contacts table** all at a time. But I want to assign different range of data to them. For Example: if '**A**', '**B**' & '**C**' all logs-in at the same time and access the table 'contacts' in front end, I want 
'**A**' to show data from **1-500**. 
'**B**' - **501-1000**. & 
'**C**' - **1001-1500** etc.

If someone can help me in the right direction to how to achieve this, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: This is a very general question... you should try a few things and then come back with more specific questions. In general, one does not ask for others here to solve general programming. You need to try solving it yourself first.

Comment: I tried different approaches with COUNT and LIMIT and joining tables but with no luck. I just want some guidance to proceed. Don't we generally ask directions if we are lost.

Comment: more details must be known like for example how do you determine each one gets 500 is it because there are 1500/3 logged in persons? and do you just assign them based on alphabetical order, these things must be defined before anyone will try to help you.

Comment: No sir, I took a general example. In real, I've 8 lac plus data in the table and I want all logged in users (which can be 5 to 10) to access those dates serially like if one gets from 1 to 500 next one will get from 501 to 1000 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Figured it out.

I created three input fields and one more column in contacts table named 'assigned_to' with default value of '0'.
The field are -

1. Select field for employee ID
2. Min(input[type=text]) range field
3. Max(input[type=text]) range field

I populated the MIN range and MAX range field using query

```
select MIN(id) as minid from contacts_table WHERE assigned_to=0
select MAX(id) as maxid from contacts_table WHERE assigned_to=0
```

Then upon post of the form I inserted the employee_id in the assigned_to column of contact table.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['assign'])) {
        $sel_emp = $_POST['sel_emp'];
        $min_range = $_POST['min_range'];
        $max_range = $_POST['max_range'];
        $sqli = "UPDATE contacts_table SET `assigned_to`='$sel_emp' WHERE `assigned_to`='0' AND id BETWEEN '$min_range' AND '$max_range'";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqli)) {
          ?>
          <script>
              $("#msg").html("Assigned");
              $("#msg").css('color', 'green');
          </script>
          <?php
        } else {
          echo mysqli_error($conn);
        }
      } ?>
```

So basically, the main query to perform the above said operation was

```
UPDATE leads SET `assigned_to`='251' WHERE `assigned_to`='0' AND id BETWEEN '1' AND '500'
```

This updated the assigned_to value with employee_id which is 251.

If anyone can provide a better solution. I'll be very thankful.